# How to design database for storage of Items in Inventory stores?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, erp

This is basically for a Production Management System that I'm currently working on. I have more than one type of Items to store in inventory (Products/Parts/Materials). I want to store them in Inventory stores which are composed of(Store, Section, Rack, Bin). I'm stuck while completing this design and want help from you people to brainstorm some ideas on how I can complete this design.

This is what I have right now.

```
Products:
    [ID]                   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                 NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultPurchasePrice] FLOAT (53)    NOT NULL,
    [DefaultSalePrice]     FLOAT (53)    NOT NULL,
    [Description]          TEXT          NULL,
    [ItemCode]             NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [MinimumLevel]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [DateAdded]            DATE          NOT NULL,
    [LastModified]         DATETIME      NOT NULL
Stores:
    [ID]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
Storages:
    [ID]      INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StoreID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Section] INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Rack]    INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Shelf]   INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Bin]     INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Storages_Stores] FOREIGN KEY ([StoreID]) REFERENCES [dbo]. 
[Stores] ([ID])
ProductStock:
    [ProductID]         INT      NOT NULL,
    [QuantityOnHand]    INT      DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [QuantityAllocated] INT      DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [QuantityTarget]    INT      DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [LastModified]      DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductStock_Product] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([ID])
```

Problem with this design is that I'm not able to track the lotts.

Comment: Can you show example of report you are not able to generate with given data structure?

Comment: @AdinugrahaTawaqal I am not able to generate transactions that happened in stock. For example where did 100 stocks of this item A go or came from?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a really broad question, so don't be too surprised if it gets flagged for that.

With regard to what you have so far, though, I see a couple of minor issues.

`Products.Description` is `TEXT`. The [`TEXT` data type has been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for quite some time now, so you should change that to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

`ProductStock` only allows for three states for an item, and I'm not sure what `QuantityTarget` is supposed to mean. If it's an ideal inventory number, doesn't that belong in the `Products` table, along with `MinimumLevel`? I assume that `QuantityOnHand` means sellable units and `QuantityAllocated` means items that have been ordered by a customer.

If you're interested in transactional data, though, you'll need to add at least two more fields; `QuantityOnOrder` (from the vendor) and something like `QuantityInactive`, where you'll account for things like units that were damaged on receipt and are awaiting return to the vendor. Basically any units you own, but can't sell.

That said, your data model is still missing quite a lot of entities if you want to know where something came from and where it went. On the incoming side, you haven't created `Vendors`, `CommonCarriers`, `PurchaseOrders`, `PurchaseOrderDetails`, or `Receipts`. On the outgoing side, you haven't created `Customers`, `Invoices`, `InvoiceDetails`, `Returns`, or `ReturnDetails`. And we haven't even touched on payment types, or probably twenty other things I'm not thinking of off the top of my head.

There are tons of resources on line for this kind of data modeling. The [ARTS Retail Operational Data Model](https://www.omg.org/retail-depository/arts-odm-73/) is just one, but it's very comprehensive and should give you some good pointers for further research.

Comment: I have not posted all of the database schema. I have PurchaseOrders, PurchaseOrderLines, SaleOrders, SaleOrderLines, ProductionOrders, ProductionOrderLines, RecevingLotts, ReturnLotts, Customers and many other standard tables needed to store the required Information. My concern here is focused on the storage of units in Inventory.